Do you have any idea on how to do calculator in 4 decimal places in Assembly Language Programming?
We are required to do a Calculator in Assembly Language Programming for our final output, but the problem is, it should be in 4 decimal places, and I could not accomplish that and I do not get the proper answer that should be showing since we are also only required to only use the available registers (ax,bx,cx,dx) and we cannot declare any variable.
Here's my sample source code where it only do 3 decimal places:
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

    add3 db " Addend[0.000-0.888]: 0.$"
    add4 db " Augend[0.000-0.888]: 0.$"
    add7 db " The sum is: $"

.code

main proc
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
addbase9:
    mov ah,02h
    mov dx,00118h
    int 10h 
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, add3 ;MERON
    int 21h
    
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h
    call adds9
    call addb9_identify
    mov dl,al
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h
    call adds9
    call addb9_identify
    mov cl,al
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h
    call adds9
    call addb9_identify
    mov bl,al   
    mov ax,dx
    and ax, 000fh
    mov dx, 0051h       
    mul dx  
    push ax 
    mov ax,cx
    and ax, 000fh
    mov cx, 0009h       
    mul cx
    push ax 
    mov ax,bx         
    and ax, 000fh 
    push ax 
    pop ax
    pop bx
    pop cx  
    add bx,cx
    add ax,bx
    push ax
    
    mov ah,02h
    mov dx,0218h
    int 10h 
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, add4    ;MERON
    int 21h
    
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h
    call adds9
    call addb9_identify
    mov dl,al
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h
    call adds9
    call addb9_identify
    mov cl,al
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h
    call adds9
    call addb9_identify
    mov bl,al       
    mov ax,dx    
    and ax, 000fh
    mov dx, 0051h   
    mul dx  
    push ax 
    mov ax,cx
    and ax, 000fh
    mov cx, 0009h   
    mul cx
    push ax 
    mov ax,bx         
    and ax, 000fh 
    push ax 
    pop ax
    pop bx
    pop cx  
    add bx,cx
    add ax,bx  
    mov bx,ax
    pop ax
    add ax,bx
    mov cx, 0005h   
    
additionb9:
    sub dx,dx
    mov bx, 0009h   
    div bx
    push dx
    loop additionb9
    
    mov ah,02h
    mov dx,0318h
    int 10h 
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, add7
    int 21h
    
    pop ax 
    call asciiaddb9 
    mov cl,01h      
    
b9print:
    pop ax
    call asciiaddb9
    mov ah,02h 
    mov dl,al
    int 21h
    loop b9print        
    mov dl,2Eh
    int 21h 
    mov cl,03h
    
addb9ex:
    pop ax
    call asciiaddb9
    mov ah,02h 
    mov dl,al
    int 21h
    loop addb9ex    
    
    mov ah,02h
    mov dx,0418h
    int 10h 
   

    mov ah,02h
    mov dx,0518h
    int 10h 
    
    call insert 
    cmp al,79h
    je addb9yes
    cmp al,59h
    je addb9yes
    cmp al,4Eh
    je addb9no
    cmp al,6Eh
    je addb9no
    
addb9yes: jmp addbase9
addb9no: jmp addbase9
    
adds9:
    cmp al, 30h
    jl addb9_enter
    cmp al, 38h             
    jle addb9_return    
    jg addb9_enter
addb9_return:
    ret
addb9_enter:
    jmp addb9no
    
addb9_identify:
    cmp al,41h 
    jge letnum_addb9
    jl num_addb9
    
num_addb9:
    sub al,30h
    jmp addb9_ret
    
letnum_addb9:
    sub al,37h
    jmp addb9_ret
addb9_ret:
    ret 
    
asciiaddb9:
   cmp al,0Ah 
   jge asciilet_addb9
   jl asciinum_addb9 
   
asciinum_addb9:
   add al,30h
   jmp asciiret_addb9
   
asciilet_addb9:
   add al, 37h
   jmp asciiret_addb9
asciiret_addb9:
   ret
insert:
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    ret


stop:
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
main endp
end main

I have tried doing the logic that comes up on my mind but I only get the result like: 0.1111 + 0.1111  = 1.0❤︎10

If your numbers are in [0, 0.888] just scale them by 1000 to be in [0, 888], do the addition, and then print the result putting the decimal dot between the thousands and the hundreds.
